# how to get more than one minumum value from an int array?

Tags: java

I am trying to get at least 5 minimum values from an array of `int`'s. My code attached works but it skips few values!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 7, 8, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 2, 22, 23};
    int min = 0;
    int index = 0;
    String output = "";
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
        min = array[x];
        index++;
        for(int i = index, limit = array.length; i < limit; ++i){
            if(array[i] <= min){
                min = array[i];
                index = i + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        output += index + "\t";               
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the array first?

Comment: Are you looking for duplicate minimums?

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur The question is in the title.

Comment: yes we need duplicate minimums as well

Answer (score 10):

```
Arrays.sort(array);
return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, 5);
```

---

If you don't want to mutate the array passed in (ie you want to leave it unsorted), add this line first:

```
int[] array = Arrays.copyOf(array);
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could sort the array using Arrays.sort() and then take the first five values:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Now `array[0]` to `array[4]` contain the lowest 5 values.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get 5 minimum values, I agree with Bohemian's Answer.
If you want to show the position of the array,such as 1,2,4,7,10, your demo is skips 2,
try my test...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int getNum = 5;
    int step = 0;
    String output = "";
    int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 7, 8, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 2, 22, 23};
    int arrayClone[] = array.clone();
    Arrays.sort(array);
    int arrayResult[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, getNum); //the arrayResult is what you want minimum values

    ploop:for (int i:arrayResult) {
        int index = 1;
        for (int j :arrayClone) {
            if(j==i){
                step++;
                output += index + "\t"; 
                if (step>=getNum) {
                    break ploop;
                }                    
            }
            index++;
        }
    }  

    System.out.println(output);        
}
```